GAM: which tensor to use when modelling single and interaction effects?
I am a bit confused about how to model single effect and interaction effects in gam. I think my question is quite straighforward, but somehow Ican't get the answer right. (and chatGPT seems confused on that one as well...)
I am interesting in modelling effect of the temperature, precipitation and their interaction on stem density. I am interested in their individal and interactive effect.
Now, which tensor to use for interaction?
what is correct: - using te
gam(y ~  s(tmp) + s(prcp) + te(tmp, prcp) )

or instead, using ti
gam(y ~  s(tmp) + s(prcp) + ti(tmp, prcp)) 

or, I can use te() only if single terms are not present?
gam(y ~ te(tmp, prcp)) 

Is there a simple answer for this question? It using te() along the s() terms would not be allowed in a single model, why it is still possible to run in R?
Thank you for your thoughts!
PS: Based on answers here, it seems correct to decomposed effects between single and interaction using ti() (ie. it is correct to use s(x) + ti(x1,x2)) but maybe not s(x) + te(x,x2)). But I wish to double check.

s(x + ti(x1,x2)) is incorrect syntax. Have you studied help("te")? You can use your third model or gam(y ~  ti(tmp) + ti(prcp) + ti(tmp, prcp)).

In a standard linear regression coded in R with the lm() function, interactions are typically modeled with the * operator, which does the following:

Models the main effects of the predictors on the outcome.
Models their interactions as well.

For GAMs, you can think of s() for singular terms / main effects and the ti() as the interaction between the predictors. The ti() function in particular models the interaction after the inclusion of the main effects in the model.
By comparison, you can model just the interaction in lm() without the inclusion of main effects with the : operator. The GAM equivalent is just using the ti() function with two variables, which just models the tensor interaction between two variables but doesn't include the partialed independent main effects as well. The te() function instead produces a full tensor product smooth, which won't include the separate independent effects of the predictors by themselves.
By the wording of your question, you more than likely want something like this for your gam() formula call:
y ~ ti(x1) + ti(x2) + ti(x1,x2)

The reason is that the s() and ti() functions have different default spline bases.

"you can model just the interaction in lm() without the inclusion of main effects with the : operator. The GAM equivalent is the te() function". I don't believe that's correct. Read the documentation in help("te") starting with "It is sometimes useful to investigate smooth models with a main-effects + interactions structure ...". te is equivalent to * in lm formulas. ti is closer to :.

I made some slight amendments to my answer (Gavin Simpson once pointed out that ti() produces the same default spline bases so that structure should have been in my original code) and you are right that ti() by itself is equivalent to just :, but I don't think it is correct to say te() is the same as *. I just checked by fitting something like te(x1,x2) and it did not produce an independent smooth for the predictors separately. Perhaps you could clarify what you mean, as I'm perhaps missing what you mean.

I mean that x * y models main effects and interaction and that would be equivalent to the full tensor smooth te(x, y). In contrast, ti can be used if you need to examine main effects and interaction separately:  ti(x) + ti(y) + ti(x, y) . In practice, I rarely have reason to use ti over te.

@ShawnHemelstrand as te(x,z) fits ti(x)+ ti(z) + ti(x,z) in an efficient way so it does include the "main" effects of x and of z on the response y. The main issue with te() is that because of how it forms the basis, there is no way to separate the main effect from the pure interaction with that basis. (You can with t2(..., full = TRUE) for example.) But the ti(x) + ti(z) + ti(x,z) version of the model is not the same as the te(x,z) model as the latter has fewer smoothing parameters than the former.

Yes, this is already my understanding. Perhaps the semantics are difficult for me to explain (I seem to have had this issue multiple times when describing the spline terms for GAMs), but I already understand that the main effects and interaction are both wrapped up in the same term of te(). My point was rather what you said, that ti() separates the main effect from the pure interaction, so that one can see the independent main effects in a way analogous to using * in lm() (which I again understand is not the exact same thing).

@ShawnHemelstrand I would say that ti() is like the x:z term; * is shorthand for main effects and interaction. which is not what ti() does. I don't think there is a nice analogy to parametric interactions for te()

Yes, we have the same understanding. I meant that having something like ti(x1) + ti(x2) + ti(x1,x2) is analogous to *, where the ti(x1,x2) by itself is analogous to : instead. Maybe my logic wasn't clear in my past comments, but I see now where the contention is now with how I described it.
